# Use LatLng Double to query GeoTiff in geotrellis (scala)

Tags: geotiff-tiff, terrain, geotrellis

I am currently trying to read bigtiffs into geotrellis in Scala to read single band terrain geotiffs. I can load them successfully, and query data/access CRS and extent info by

`val tiffPath: String = "/Users/vb/Misc/testTiffs/00N46E006.geotiff"
    val geoTiff: SinglebandGeoTiff = GeoTiffReader.readSingleband(tiffPath)
    val tile = geoTiff.tile
    val extent = geoTiff.extent
    val crs: CRS =   geoTiff.crs
    println(tile.getDouble(100,1))`

However I want to be able to access the value by something like

`tile.get(latitudeDouble, longitudeDouble)`

Where latitudeDouble and longitudeDouble are real values on this tile. Using the Value reader functionality seems promising, but this isn't a multilayer tiff, so i'm not sure it's the right thing.

http://geotrellis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/spark.html#value-readers

Answer (score 1):

Answer via the geotrellis support board:

`val (col, row) = geoTiff.rasterExtent.mapToGrid(lat,lon)`

This generates location within tile where the lat/lon value resides.

Geotrellis board link: https://gitter.im/geotrellis/geotrellis